# Correct Usage of NumberFormatter textAttributesFor Variables?

Tags: cocoa, foundation, nsnumberformatter

The Foundation class, NumberFormatter, has a collection of instance variables under the category:

> Configuring the Display of Numeric Values

that are all very similar:

```
var textAttributesForNegativeValues: [String : Any]?
var textAttributesForPositiveValues: [String : Any]?
//...
```

From what I can tell, these are rarely used, and as such, I haven't been able to find a single example of how to use them, and the [Apple API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter#topics) is mute on the issue.

So, does anyone know how to properly use these variables / why they would be used in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple's docs are not the best organised these days, and often useful links seem to have gone AWOL - as here. Read the section on custom formats in the number section of Apple's [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1), and follow the references in it, and you should find the answers you seek.

HTH

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, textAttributesForPositiveNumbers is just another way of setting the positiveFormat variable? If so, what value goes in the Any field, because it isn't the numberFormatter. If not, then I don't think the Data Formatting Guide mentioned these variables.

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` provides a number of properties which all you to set different rules for positive and negative values, that custom format section demonstrates the pattern. The two properties you mention set text attributes, and you'll find out about those by reading docs related to `NSAttributedString` etc. what these properties do is allow, for example, the formatting of negative numbers in red. Just follow the doc chains (which admittedly can be a challenge), think about the model of formatting that is provided, try out code, and the gaps should fill in. HTH